# How to reload data on a subview if the model is presented using UIModalPresentationFormSheet

Tags: ipad, uitableview, modal-dialog, presentmodalviewcontroller, reloaddata

I have implemented a UIModalPresentationFormSheet in my iPad application.  The new view partially covers the sub view and allows the user to make a choice.  This all works great, however...

When the user selects an option I would like to update the underlying view with the new details, but cannot get it to work!

I have tried using setNeedsDisplay or [table reloadData]; in both the viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear methods.

Some code for codes sake:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self updateUserDetails];
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self updateUserDetails];   
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)updateUserDetails {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:selection forKey:@"userDetail"];
}
```

My transition is as follows.  If this line is commented out then the application functions as expected:

```
myNavigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set 
`self.view.autolayoutSubviews = NO;` 
UI will change your view's size for UIModalPresentationFormSheet. This may be break the reload process.

Comment: "This may be break the reload process." Please expand.

Comment: I don't know the details about the reload process, I mean when use the UIModalPresentationFormSheet style, system will change your view's size, and your view controller will auto layout subviews, include changing the tableview's size, this may take a problem when you invoke reload. We can't read the source code, We don't know what  happened, but this works out for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the reloading of data near the code where you detect the selection of the user, not in the `viewWillAppear` of `viewDidAppear`.